# как вычислить второй по величине элемент массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

`var x = [12,6,8,3]` первый по величине `12`, нужно найти второй элемент `8`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = [12, 6, 8, 3];
x.sort((a, b) => b - a);
console.log(x[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для большого массива сортировка невыгодна. Достаточно пройти по массиву один раз.

```
Хранить два текущих значения `Max` и `Second`
На каждом шаге:
  Если очередное значение A[i] >= Max:
     Second = Max
     Max = A[i]
  иначе если A[i] > Second:
     Second = A[i]
```